# Arokh HaShulchan and shiur tzitzith

Tags: halacha, clothing, tzitzis, shiurim-measurements, aruch-hashulchan

A *braita* cited authoritatively in the Talmud (Menachoth 40b-41a) seems to be pretty explicit that only a garment sufficient to cover a majority of a child is obligated in *tzitzith*:

> טלית שהקטן מתכסה בו ראשו ורובו
>   והגדול יוצא בה דרך עראי חייבת בציצית
>   אין הקטן מתכסה בו ראשו ורובו אע"פ שהגדול יוצא בה עראי פטורה
>
> A cloak with which a minor can cover his head and majority (of his body) and an adult would go out in it occasionally is obligated in tzitzith.  If the minor can not cover his head and majority with it, even though an adult would occasionally go out in it, it is exempt.

Nonetheless, the *Arokh HaShulchan* ([OC 16:5](http://www.sefaria.org/Aruch_HaShulchan.1.16.5?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) attempts to defend a prevalent lenient practice regarding wearing small garments with *tzitzit*, even in *reshut harabim* (public domain) on Shabbath, which had previously been decried as a desecration of Shabbath, by arguing that any sized garment is obligated in *tzitzith*:

> טלית קטן שתחת הבגדים אינה צריכה שיעור כלל, דאם רק יש בו ארבע כנפות – חייב בציצית
>
> ... A *tallit katan* worn under the clothes does not require any (minimum) measurement at all, for if it has four corners - it is obligated in *tzitzith*.

(See also *op. cit.* OC 8:4 and 10:20) Does this mean that the practice at the time was indeed to append *tzitzith* to every size of garment - e.g. scarves, neckties, etc?  Wouldn't it be a *tarti d'satri* (contradiction) for a person to be wearing a small *tallit* simultaneously with - e.g. a scarf?  Similarly, nowadays, if someone is wearing a less-than-shiur *tallith katan* (e.g. an adolescent), does that mean he must be relying on the Arokh HaShulchan and should not also wear a necktie?

Comment: "Does this mean that the practice at the time was indeed to append tzitzith to every size of garment - e.g. scarves, neckties, etc?" Why did you tag this [tag:halacha] when you seem to be asking a (rather trivial) [tag:history] question?

Comment: "any sized garment is obligated in tzitzith" Perhaps include the relevant quote (it's obviously not the one you already quoted which just discusses "a tallit katan worn under the clothes")? I don't think that's an accurate representation of his position.

Comment: I feel like you aren't even reading the Arukh haShulchan... Did you even read the whole paragraph you cite? Or did you just hear that he says to put tzitzit on a napkin and start asking ranty questions trying to make a point that that position is crazy?

Comment: @DoubleAA If you have an alternate explanation of his words, that might be an answer.

Comment: @DoubleAA Are you arguing a that his distinction is between inner and outer garments?  Accordingly, if one were to wear his tallit katan on the outside, the Arokh HaShulchan would require a shiur? And foot wraps might require tzitzith?

Comment: I'm not arguing that. The Arukh haShluchan _literally_ wrote it! He's not an idiot and he knows no one puts tzitzit on a necktie.

Comment: @DoubleAA Assuming that is the interpretation of his words, what would be the source for such a distinction?

Comment: He claims the Nimmukei Yosef and Ritva apparently support him, so try checking there. Probably someone could quibble with his reads of them if they wanted to, but that's neither here nor there. You don't have to think he's right to realize he's not so foolish to have forgotten about scarves and napkins.

Comment: @DoubleAA Which suggests the trivial history point is less than trivial since I'm not clear whether or not it was a Judaean custom to where neckties where the Arokh HaShulchan lived.

Comment: @DoubleAA I'm also not clear on whether "napkins" were considered men's fashion accessories in the culture of the Arokh HaShulchan.

Comment: just look at pictures/videos from then https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=87XlDRjmPME if you really need proof

Comment: @Loewian Regarding napkins as men's fashion accessories, think the practice of those who use snuff with regularity.